# Create new Core 2.0 web project, core libraries can't be loaded

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Visual Studio 2017, when creating a new ASP.NET Core Web project with ASP.NET Core 2.0, e.g. React w/ Flux preset, the core dlls fail to load. Nuget package restore does nothing, but I can uninstall and reinstall the AspNetCore.All package. If I do this, I get the following error:

> Error MSB3073 The command "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js" exited with code 8.    ReactTest   [PATH]\source\repos\ReactTest\ReactTest\ReactTest.csproj    33

I don't suspect this is a real error, I suspect it's because of the initial package install failure. I have been able to perform this operation on other devices, so I know that I am following the correct processes and have the correct SDKs and toolsets installed. I have repaired, and uninstalled / reinstalled Visual Studio 2017 with reboot and nothing has fixed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. My version of node.js was ancient (in web terms...). I installed the latest version (8.8.1) and everything was fine.

Comment: I had forgotten to reply to this question, but yes this is what did it for me as well. For some reason, VS does not update you to the necessary version of node if it's already installed.